# Format to merge Data using Sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format 

`Room : L1,
Name : Test,
DOB : 2017-10-12,
Section : ABC,
Name : BTest2,
Status : APPROVE,
DOB : 2017-10-12,
Rule : forward,
Comment : Testing comment,
Room : L2,
Name : Test2,
DOB : 2017-10-11,
Rule : Backward,`

I am trying to get output in below format 

`Room : L1,Name : Test,DOB : 2017-10-12,Section : ABC,
Room : L1,Name : BTest2,Status : APPROVE,DOB : 2017-10-12,Rule : forward,Comment : Testing comment,
Room : L2,Name : Test2,DOB : 2017-10-11,Rule : Backward,`

I tried using awk and sed to format the data but since the pattern is not very consistent I am unable to do so. Is there anyways to do it based on occurrence of Name only . In below example I am using both Name and Comment and hence it failing.

`awk '/^Room/{s=$0} /^Name/ && match(p,/^Comment/){$0=sprintf("%s%s%s",s,ORS,$0)} {print;p=$0}' test.txt | sed ':a;/Comment/!{N;s/\n//g;ba}'`

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: a smaller set of sample data might simplify your problem description. Are you trying to get all the "fields" onto one line? Please update your Q so your need is clearer. Good luck.

Comment: Hi. I am not trying to merge all fields in a single line . But merge Room with all records between two occurance of Name. This was smallest data set I could make .

Comment: @user2854333, but `DOB` key is also occurs twice in `Room: L1` - consider updating your output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest .. I would feel Name as key as Name occurs 1st string at start of new set which needs to merged with last Room

Comment: @user2854333, elaborate your logic: should only `Name` key be considered as a cause of separation?

Comment: Yes .. we need to merge the data between 2 occurrence of name with last occurrence of room .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^Room/{ if (R){ print ""; delete keys } R=$0; k=$3 }
     /^Name/{ keys[k $1]++ }
     { printf "%s%s", (keys[k $1] > 1? ORS R : ""), $0 }
     END{ print "" }' file
```

The output:

```
Room : L1,Name : Test,DOB : 2017-10-12,Section : ABC,
Room : L1,Name : BTest2,Status : APPROVE,DOB : 2017-10-12,Rule : forward,Comment : Testing comment,
Room : L2,Name : Test2,DOB : 2017-10-11,Rule : Backward,
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^Room/          {room=$0;                  next}
     NR==2 && /^Name/ {printf("%s%s",room,$0);   next}
     NR>2  && /^Name/ {printf("\n%s%s",room,$0); next}
     {printf("%s",$0)}
     END{print ""}' file
```

Output:

```
Room : L1,Name : Test,DOB : 2017-10-12,Section : ABC,
Room : L1,Name : BTest2,Status : APPROVE,DOB : 2017-10-12,Rule : forward,Comment : Testing comment,
Room : L2,Name : Test2,DOB : 2017-10-11,Rule : Backward,
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^Room/{:a;N;s/^((.*, )(Name).*\n)\3/\1\2\3/;tb;/\nRoom/!s/\n/ /;ta;:b;P;D}' file
```

This gathers up lines between `Room`'s into a single line and then inserts a newline and the `Room` field where there are multiple `Name` fields.